# CSS properties inheritance and overriding in a nested HTML structure

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, nested

Text in the snippet basically explains itself what I want to achieve. I want inner divs, that do not have a `bg-` class, to inherit border color, but then, if color changes, deeper divs then have that color inherited. I don't really have control over how deep nesting happens or how divs are structured and how (to which divs) color class names are assigned.

Using SCSS, so I have more colors and loop through them, but can't figure out how (if possible at all) to achieve such color inheritance.

Not sure if this is even possible to achieve easily, but here's what I have:

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

div.area {
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

div.bg-orange {
  background-color: sandybrown;
  border-color: orange;
}

div.bg-orange .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: orange;
}

div.bg-red {
  background-color: lightpink;
  border-color: red;
}

div.bg-red .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: red;
}

div.bg-green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-color: green;
}

div.bg-green .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: green;
}

div.bg-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-color: blue;
}

div.bg-blue .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="area bg-blue">
  <div class="area">Plain</div>
  <div class="area bg-green">
    Green
    <div class="area bg-red">Red</div>
    <div class="area">
      Should should be green border
      <div>Plain no border</div>
      <div class="area">Plain should be green border</div>
      <div class="area bg-red">
        Red
        <div class="area bg-orange">
          Orange
          <div class="area">Plain should be orange border</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS variables. The trick is that the custom property (the CSS variable) is inherited until you override it at a deeper level.

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}
div.area {
  border: 2px solid var(--c,gray);
}

div.bg-orange {
  background-color: sandybrown;
  --c: orange;
}

div.bg-red {
  background-color: lightpink;
  --c: red;
}
div.bg-green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  --c: green;
}
div.bg-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  --c: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="area bg-blue">
  <div class="area">Plain</div>
  <div class="area bg-green">
    Green
    <div class="area bg-red">Red</div>
    <div class="area">
      Should should be green border
      <div>Plain no border</div>
      <div class="area">Plain should be green border</div>
      <div class="area bg-red">
        Red
        <div class="area bg-orange">
          Orange
          <div class="area">Plain should be orange border</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the desired result?

I just replaced assigned color with `inherit` wherever you have `.area:not([class*="bg-"])`.

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

div.area {
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

div.bg-orange {
  background-color: sandybrown;
  border-color: orange;
}

div.bg-orange .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: inherit;
}

div.bg-red {
  background-color: lightpink;
  border-color: red;
}

div.bg-red .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: inherit;
}

div.bg-green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-color: green;
}

div.bg-green .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: inherit;
}

div.bg-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-color: blue;
}

div.bg-blue .area:not([class*="bg-"]) {
  border-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="area bg-blue">
  <div class="area">Plain</div>
  <div class="area bg-green">
    Green
    <div class="area bg-red">Red</div>
    <div class="area">
      Should should be green border
      <div>Plain no border</div>
      <div class="area">Plain should be green border</div>
      <div class="area bg-red">
        Red
        <div class="area bg-orange">
          Orange
          <div class="area">Plain should be orange border</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That sure seems to work. I'm baffled by how specificity is apparently affected by the rule value.

Comment: Seemed intuitive. I think the specificity is affected by the additional class (`.area`) being appended to the `div.` selector.

Comment: I don't understand. Your CSS selectors are identical to the originals, no?

Comment: @isherwood - Yes. I most likely am misinterpreting your first comment.

Comment: I'm just confused why changing what's effectively just a color value makes a rule that was previously overridden take precedence. Maybe I'm working the math wrong.

Comment: After posting a question, figured I could use `inherit`, but this would not work if `.area` is inside a `div` without any class name. @Temani's answer on the other hand works perfectly no matter how nesting is structured. But thank you for the suggestion